# How to add a line separated check box text in java?

Tags: java, swing

I have a data in database, such as

```
A

AB\n
CDE

ABCD\n
E

ABC\n
DE\n
```

Can I set these texts to a check box, in this state(line separated)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4):

Put the string between tags `<html></html>` and replace each `\n` with `<br/>`. For example, this:

```
AB\nCD
```

... must become this:

```
<html>AB<br/>CD</html>
```

Comment: Yes! It works if the db entry has html and br tags. Can't I handle it in code.

Comment: @RSST Why can't you handle it in code? It's a matter of putting something at the front, something at the end, and a simple replace. Seems rather simple actually.

Comment: @RSST you'll _have to_ handle it in code for this to work. The text, as it comes from the data base, won't be displayed in separate lines. It's mandatory that you convert it to html, which is a simple operation, I agree with Cruncher's comment

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML tags on Swing components to achieve that. See [How to use HTML in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)